# multi language IDE

Tags: java, c++, python, eclipse, visual-studio

I have a software that uses multiple languages, which are all available as eclipse plugins (java, c++, python). The exes call each other. I was wondering if there is a way I could debug all these languages using eclipse. I have the sources for all of them, and all of them are projects in eclipse, but so far they work independently, and I was wondering whether, for example, if I added a break point in a C++ code and called a java program that calls the C++ code, the execution would pause when it reaches the C++ breakpoint. I think this is somehow similar to 'attaching to a process' in Visual Studio, though I'm not sure whether Visual Studio provides this feature either. Is it possible with eclipse or Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Eclipse has no support for multidebugger debugging. However, it might be possible to debug the same workspace in many Eclipse instance at the same time. Simply launch the debugger for each language separately by attaching to them as you said.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're proposing, are you suggesting I should open more than one instance of the Eclipse software itself ? And how do I attach to them (and who is 'them') ? I know how to do that in visual studio, but not eclipse.

Comment: @kbell67 Open multiple Eclipse on the same workspace. Eclipse itself isn't a debugger but an interface for a true debugger to which it attach to. Look for **remote debugging** in Java and **Attach to application** in CDT. For other language look in the Eclispe doc of your plugin.